# Express.js static serving not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I'm trying to apply a bootstrap theme to a file generated by Jade, but it says it cannot GET the file.

Main JS file:

```
var express = require('express')
app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){res.render('index.jade', {title: 'stuff'});});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

index.jade:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='public/lumen.min.css')
h1 
   a(href='http://example.com') test
p this is a test
```

Any solutions on this?

Comment: Where is index.jade located? Oh, and which file does it say it cannot GET?

Comment: @JasonReid In /templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`href='public/lumen.min.css'` is trying to access a file located at `__dirname + public/public/lumen.min.css` (note the double `public`).  Change that line to:

```
link(re='stylesheet', href='lumen.min.css')
```

You don't need to prepend the public directory to your `src`/`href` attributes, express is smart enough to figure that out.

For more examples of using `express.static`, check out the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).